# Python Plot Categories for a Variable in a Dataset

Tags: python, class, plot, categories

How can I plot the counts of each category (like 1, 2 and 3) for a column variable in a large dataset only with matplotlib and without using NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, SciKit-Learn, etc.?

Comment: Have you looked at `plt.hist`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response :) I think that is what I have to use, but not sure how to call the categories from one column of a big dataset and then plot using plt.hist

Comment: Give a more detailed example, and I can give you a code snippet.

Comment: For example if my variable is an integer with the classes 1, 2 and 3. The dataset is more than 1000 rows and I need to plot the classes. So I need a bar chart with the counts of each class shown.